# How can I monitor this AC circuit?

Tags: relay

I have a machine that has a circuit more complicated than this, but this to make things simple:

The voltage source is 24 VAC coming from a PLC, and it has more than 100 × (bulb + resistor + switch).

How can I insert one relay in this circuit to be able to perform a command outside this circuit when ONE or more switches is closed?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdS5wl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question is: Why this circuit didn't work?

Relay model: RMI 45

Datasheet: 
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1430520.pdf

Update: When one of the switches closes, the lamp don't go on and the relay keeps closing and opening frequently.

Comment: Why do your lamps have resistors across them?

Comment: the resistor is to ensure continuity if the bulb is burned out.

Comment: What is the current per lamp circuit when a switch is closed? You've shown the default 100 ohms for both the resistor and the lamp. (Double-click to edit component properties.)

Comment: The bulbs draw 50mA.

Comment: I added a question, I hope you answer it.

Comment: My question is: What is the part number of the relay you added? Please [edit] to include the part number and a link to the datasheet.

Comment: What you wanted is done.

Comment: Nope. You've given the series number. There are seven part numbers in the DC series and six in the AC series. We need the "ordering key" or full part number. [Edit] again.

Comment: I can't reach this information right now, probably in the future, can you tell me a general idea about why the relay keeps on off frequently, this happened with every relay I have, no matter if it is AC or DC.

Comment: Because you haven't got adequate current / voltage to operate the relay. You've connected it in series with the lamps.

Answer (score 2):

for this aopplication you can use a current-sensing relay, as you have drawn. this is a different type of relay to much more the more common potential relay.

Comment: Oops, ignore my earlier answer. I misunderstood what the asker was trying to do; this is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your amswer, is there any current sensor for sensing a very low current? because the bulbs draw very little current, especially when there is only one switch closed.

Comment: Given that the current can vary by over two orders of magnitude (there's over 100 switches, any or all of which may be closed at once, and it needs to detect even just one), I'm not sure how easy it will be to find a suitable relay. It would need to be able to detect as low as ~200 milliamps, but withstand as much as 24+ amps without breaking or having too much voltage drop.

Comment: @Jasen, I have 108 switch in one machine, so I need 108x3=324 diodes, it is too much!

Comment: is is about $6  or you can use bridge rectifiers to reduce the parts count, bur yeah in the case of 100 signals the current sensing realy is certainly easier. to install and if you time is more than $5 per hour cheaper too..

Comment: Diodes are not practical at all, there is no room for them and I can't install them in an exposed place. the workers may destroy them!

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0EoP5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A diode dropping circuit consisting of D1 to D6 will drop about 2.1 V in both forward and reverse direction. This is enough to power a bidirectional opto-isolator with 10 mA for most of each half-cycle.*

- The circuit will work with 100 mA (one lamp + resistor).
- The circuit will work with 10 A (100 lamps + resistors).
- Average current trough D1 to D6 will be 5 A with 100 lamps. Diodes should be rated at ≥ 10 A.
- Diodes will each dissipate *P = VI = 0.7 × 5 = 3.5* W when 100 lamps are on so they'll need adequate ventilation.
- Q1 can be used to drive a logic circuit or a relay switching circuit. (Note that it can only switch a few milliamps due to the limits of the opto-isolator's current transfer ratio.)

Comment: Thank you, I don't care how many lamps are lit, I only want to close a relay when one switch closes, if it's too much current it's OK to shut down the circuit, the most important thing is to keep the rely closed as long as one of the switches is closed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Do you understand that this circuit can detect one lamp or 100 lamps? "*...  if it's too much current it's OK to shut down the circuit, the most important thing is to keep the rely closed as long as one of the switches is closed.*"  No, if the circuit shuts down you will lose the relay too.

Comment: I understood you, and my comment is for getting rid of some components if possible.

Comment: Analyse the circuit. What would you propose removing and why?

Comment: I mean the ventilation part, I can't guarantee good one.  Can I connect a 24VAC to the Q1?

Comment: No. Transistors require a DC supply. If you aren't sure what an opto-isolator is then you will need help with this circuit.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated, please bear with me, I am learning..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106401/discussion-between-shaydzmi-and-transistor).

Comment: Can a normal opto-isolator do the job?

Comment: I'm not recommending this circuit as there is still information missing from your original question. You need to specify the range of current you are trying to detect. That means one lamp and resistor and "more than 100" lamps and resistors. I notice that you did not provide all the information requested in the comments below your question ten months ago. The big problem is why you want to monitor current in the first place. It looks to me as though you want to monitor whether or not one or more switches are turned on and you have decided that monitoring current is the best way. It might not.

Comment: My original question was to operate a relay when at least one of the switches is closed.  The current monitoring came as an option from the comments. And I don't know what information is missing.. And yes it has been more than 10 months and I am still struggling to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a current transformer.

Your load varies from a minimum of 24 V / 500 Ω = 48 mA (one switch on, lamp burned out) to a maximum of 100 × lamp              + resistor current. If your lamps are 1.2W (480 Ω), then the maximum would be almost 10 A.

If you use a 200:1 current transformer, then the secondary current will range from 0.24 mA to 50 mA. This is more than enough to activate a transistor that can operate your "common" relay.

Normally, you would "burden" a current transformer with a resistor in order to get a linear response. In this case, we don't care about linearity at all, so we use a zener diode to limit the voltage instead. A 5V zener will only be dissipating about 250 mW in the worst case (all lights on).

We take 0.1 mA from this 5V supply to drive a Darlington transistor pair. Another bridge rectifier allows us to control a relay that has a 24VAC coil (which matches your power source).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEXfGQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is a variation of this circuit that eliminates the two bridge rectifiers. The only catch is that you now need to make sure that the phasing of the transformer is correct. Note that Q1 and Q2 are Darlington transistors internally.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnjZT0.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much.

Lamp are like this:
https://www.narva.com.au/products/47508

the hole circuit is protected with a 10a fuse, never burned out unless a short circuit happend.

what kind of current transformer I need?

thank you again.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer to reflect the actual lamp and resistor values, switching to a 200:1 transformer. [Any of these](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/transformers/current-sense-transformers/163?k=current+transformer&k=&pkeyword=current+transformer&sv=0&sf=1&FV=-8%7C163%2C2015%7C139802&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25) would be fine.

Comment: Thank you, can you find for me a one standalone device to do all this work? like a current sensor? because I have a lot of machines, and each machine has 2 circuits, so it will be easier to deal with all of them.

Comment: No. This site does not do product recommendations. But try searching for "PLC current sense switch". There are plenty of products out there.

Comment: why all the zeners and resistors? TIP122 is not harmed by 100mA base current

Comment: you could probably do a simpler version using a triac

Comment: @Jasen: You need D1 and D2 in any case, to protect each transistor from reverse Vbe and to allow the base current to flow. They might as well be zeners. And the resistor values could be reduced (the high value was a carryover from the top circuit) -- possibly to zero, but I'd be inclined to keep some resistance there to protect against transients.

Comment: And yes, you probably could drive the gate of a sensitive triac directly from the CT. Why don't you write that up as your own answer?

Comment: fair call, if he's running incandescent lamps there will be transients at power on, and if and fail shorted.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: The CT doesn't  affect the voltage and current going to the switches?

Comment: No. The voltage drop across the primary is 1/200 of the voltage on the secondary. 5V/200 = 25 mV, completely insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using 108 diodes, a relay and an electrolytic capacitor.

[image]

A PCB would make the task less difficult.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is almost impossible to install this quantity of diodes, especially in an exposed area.

Comment: Anytime, Shaydzmi. I presumed that the PCB would be located in the machine control panel.