# Can someone explain and help me with this circuit?

Tags: ac, relay, dc

This is a board that controls a circular knitting machine, this machine has 108 MPF feeders, those feeders controls 108 yarn, when a yarn breaks the feeder lights its bulb the machine decelerates to stop, at this moment, the worker must fix the yarn and run the machine again, I want to take 2 wires from somewhere to activate a relay when the switch of one or more is closed I want to use this relay to operate a bulb I'll put it on the top of the machine so the worker can see it easily and come to fix the yarn again:

please see the pictures below:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**This question contains a unique parts which differentiate it from [my other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491166), I'am asking for the function of the components in this circuit and how can I benefit from them.**

Comment: Can you please tell us more about this circuit? What does it do? For what do you would like to use the wires?

Comment: Do you already have the 24VAC from another part of the circuit, and just want to add "MPF Feeder", or something in addition to MPF Feeder, to actuate the same TLP504A? Or when MPF Feeder activates, activate another TLP504A? Or something simpler, like tap into ground and "+24VAC" shown above and wire that to a 24VAC relay?

Comment: Just for your information: The D14 diode is a 1N4007 (1000V Ur), the Capacitor C1? is a 100nF 10% / 63V type and the Diode D13 is a U1520 (max. 15 A) its 9728 is a date code (YYWW = 1997 week 28).

Comment: @sgt_johnny @ rdtsc I added more information and full pictures of the board.

Comment: You could do this in a non-invasive manner using a optosensor attached to the led. Make your own opto coupler.

Comment: @ Passerby Please show me how to do this. I'm just a beginner!

Comment: https://hestiapi.com/why-pay-the-premium-for-smart-devices/ or https://www.diystompboxes.com/smfforum/index.php?topic=113641.0 you hot glue, heat shrink or otherwise attach the led to a LDR. This is electrically isolated so the rest of your add on circuit is powered separately.  The rest of the circuit can be a typical light or dark sensing light bulb setup.

Comment: Is this the real story behind your previous question? [How can I monitor this AC circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491166/how-can-i-monitor-this-ac-circuit) If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: @Dave Tweed , Yes it is the same story, but the questions are different. in this topic I'm asking for explanation of the components function in this circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the circuit diagram based on my interpretation of the photographs.

[image]

U 1520 is a 15A diode. When the switch is closed the optocoupler in TLP 504A would be turned on and would shut-down the machine through a relay.

The circuit diagram may be verified for its correctness.

A relay driver circuit is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, can you specify for me a place in this circuit from where I can hook a transistor or thing similar to drive a relay?

Comment: You need to first confirm, by physically checking on the PCB, that this circuit diagram is correct.

Comment: You may also trace the circuit, after the optocoupler, to see how the relay is being driven.

Comment: 1- Your circuit diagram is correct. 2- The relay I want has nothing to do in this board at all. 3- It is difficult  for me as a beginner, to trace that circuit after the optocoupler.

Comment: A relay driver circuit is added.

Comment: Hi Shaydzmi, Could you please accept my answer?

Comment: Done! Thank you..